# Добавление hostapd в автозагрузку с параметром

Tags: linux

Для создания точки доступа для дальнейшего подключения по VNC, мне необходимо добавить hostapd в автозапуск, но сделать мне это надо с параметром -ddd, как можно добавить hostapd в автозапуск с параметром -ddd

```
update-rc.d hostapd enable
```

Comment: в /etc/init.d создать скрипт. сделать исполняемым. скрипт добавить в автозагрузку. внутри скрипта будет запуск программы с параметром

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по упоминанию скрипта `update-rc.d`, речь идёт о дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* либо об одном из множества его «наследников».

в дистрибутивном пакете *hostapd* имеется файл `/etc/default/hostapd`, в котором есть даже заготовка для добавления опций запуска демона:

```
#DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

раскомментируйте строку и впишите нужные вам опции (есть `-d` — «показать больше отладочных сообщений», есть и `-dd` — «показать ещё больше отладочных сообщений», а вот `-ddd` — нет):

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-dd"
```

Comment: Ничего не вышло. Попросту не подгружается после запуска системы.

Comment: 1. смотрите логи. 2. пробуйте запустить вручную: `$ sudo /etc/init.d/hostapd start` и опять смотрите логи.

Comment: судя по ману, есть опция `-d`, есть она же продублированная — `-dd`, а вот «протретированной» в мане нет.